# Значение по умолчанию в списке Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Есть столбец таблицы, который выводит список возможных статусов проекта:

```
<form th:action="@{'/tasks/' + ${project.id} + '/edit'}" method="POST">
    <input id="taskStatus" name="task" type="hidden" th:value="${t.id}"/>
    <select name="TaskStatus" th:field="${taskStatusName}">
        <option th:each="s : ${findAllStatus}"  th:value="*{s}" th:text="${s.status}" th:name="TaskStatus"></option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="add">Add project</button>
</form>
```

Пытаюсь заставить выводить значение по умолчанию - текущий статус задачи, выполняя проверку типа:

```
 <select name="TaskStatus" th:field="*{t.status.id}">
```

Но выходит ошибка:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
> target object for bean name 't' available as request attribute

Как я понял, он не может найти объект задачи. Но всю таблицу я уже пропустил через `for each`. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

**ИЗМЕНЕНИЯ**

Добавил в метод GET жестко определенный статус для теста:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tasks/{project}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView index(@PathVariable ("project")Project project) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    List<Task> findAll = taskService.findAll(project);
    List<TaskStatus> findAllStatus = taskStatusService.findAll();
    TaskStatus taskStatusName = taskStatusRepository.findByStatus("In work");
    modelAndView.addObject("taskStatusName", taskStatusName);
    modelAndView.addObject("findAllTasks", findAll);
    modelAndView.addObject("findAllStatus", findAllStatus);
    final String currentUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
    modelAndView.addObject("user", userService.findByEmail(currentUser));
    modelAndView.setViewName("tasks");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Ошибка исчезла, но значение по умолчанию не подтягивается.

Comment: попробуйте добавить требуемый объект в реквест.

Comment: добавил в метод GET жестко определенный статус для теста         TaskStatus taskStatusName = taskStatusRepository.findByStatus("In work");
        modelAndView.addObject("taskStatusName", taskStatusName);

Comment: Добавь код всего контроллера

Comment: добавил код получения списка задач

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решена, использовал `th:selected`. Надеюсь кому поможет.

```
<form th:action="@{'/tasks/' + ${project.id} + '/edit'}" method="POST">
  <input id="taskStatus" name="task" type="hidden" th:value="${t.id}"/>
  <select name="TaskStatus" >
    <option th:each="s : ${findAllStatus}"  th:value="${s}" th:text="${s.status}"
                                    th:name="TaskStatus" th:selected="${s.id == t.taskStatus.id}"></option>
  </select>
 <button type="submit" class="add">Add project</button>
</form>
```